# Shell scripting: intersperse comments between multiline logical operators

Tags: bash, shell, unix, comments, zsh

I have a multiline conditional like this:

```
command1 \
    && command2 \
    && command3
```

This is fine, but I would like to put comments after each command, like this:

```
command1 \ # Comment for command 1.
    && command2 \ # Comment for command 2.
    && command3 # Comment for command 3.
```

but the script breaks (in Bash and Zsh) because of a parsing error.

Is there a way to add comments between multiline conditionals?

NOTE: I realize that I could just create a function for each command, and then just add comments to each command in its function definition; but I would like to avoid that if possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No need to escape the comment start. You can use inline comments like this:

```
pwd && # comment1
date && # comment2
tty # comment3
```

Comment: It took a double-take for me to see the difference, but I see that the key is to (1) use the `&&` at the end of the command, not before it, and (2) avoid the use of "\". TIL `&&` acts as a kind of multiline "glue" on its own. Thanks!

Comment: @opert The version with `\ ` does not work because `\ ` always quotes the next character. Without comments this is a newline, with comments it is just a space. Placing the `\ ` after the comment does not work because in `zsh` it is not possible to end a comment before the end of a line, thus the `\ ` would be included in the comment.

Comment: @Adaephon Thanks, makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

I use snippets like this in my dotfiles to embed comments in multiline calls:

```sh
function e() {
  setsid -f                 $(: "fork into separate session")        \
    emacsclient                                                      \
      --create-frame        $(: "force new gui window")              \
      --alternate-editor='' $(: "launch emacs if daemon is missing") \
      "$@"
}
```

`:` is the standard shorthand for `true`, which succeeds while ignoring arguments. This is why `$(: "foo")` is evaluated to nothing.